# trying to restore a production postgresql db into dev box

Tags: postgresql-9.2, database-backups, database-restore

I'm running the following command to create a dump of all database on my production server:

```
prodserver:/# pg_dumpall -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1 > prod.sql
```

on my development box, I also take a backup by doing:

```
devserver:/# pg_dumpall -U postgres -h 1.1.1.1 > dev.sql
```

Then I try to restore the production database on to development like so:

```
devserver:/# psql -f prod.sql -U postgres
```

It runs with no errors. And it appears to be creating tables /import data.  I know because if I run it a second time, I get messages that certain data already exists / relationships already exist.

But when I log in like so:

```
psql -U postgres -d databasename
```

the data looks the same as the old dev data.  I tried the following with the production data supposedly restored:

```
select count(*) from widgets;
```

I compare that with the count returned when I'm using the development database and they are the same. 
It looks like the database wasn't restored properly.

Do I have to:

- a) delete the dev databsae before I restore production?
- b) restart
  postgresql?

I've been using http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pg-dumpall.html as a guide... 
I was referring to the examples at the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I also checked the following:

I opened up the prod.sql file and found insert statements like:

```
INSERT INTO widgets_to_wiget_groups VALUES (363, 15);
```

And then I did a select statement on the database to see if I had this entry in the table but I don't... maybe it's restoring it but under the context of another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run

CREATE DATABASE databasename;

to manually create the db, and then changed the restore command to:

```
devserver:/# psql -f prod.sql -U postgres -d databasename
```